# AlamofireObjectMapper responseObject method migrating issue

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift3

I have a problem with the `AlamofireObjectMapper` `responseObject` method. It's `completionHandler` changed from `Response<T, NSError> -> Void` (old) to `DataResponse<T> -> Void` (now). Maybe I don't get it but can you please tell me how can I provide backend error handling now with this change? Before, I had in completion for example `Response<Object, NSError>`. Now I can't handle both the backend error and the on success received data. Or should I use other approach?

For example now I have: Xcode 8 , swift 3, updated frameworks

```
class func getAllProducts(successCallBack:((ProductsData?) -> Void), failureCallBack: ((NSError?, ServerResponseStatusCode?) -> Void)?) {

        Alamofire.request(URLRouter.Products).responseObject {
            (response: DataResponse<ProductsData, NSError>) in

            // inside completion block code
        }
    }
```

But as I checked in the new updated AlamofireObjectMapper, this method's completion now is of form `DataResponse<T>` only, and because of this I get the error "Generic type "DataResponse" specialized with too many type parameters(got 2 but expected 1)"

Before: working Xcode 7, swift 2.2

```
class func getAllProducts(successCallBack:((ProductsData?) -> Void), failureCallBack: ((NSError?, ServerResponseStatusCode?) -> Void)?) {

        Alamofire.request(URLRouter.Products).responseObject {
            (response: Response<ProductsData, NSError>) in

            // inside completion block code
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you post your code as-is?

Comment: Yes of course, I've edited the question with more details. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In **Alamofire 4.0** using ***Swift 3.0***, you may need to reach error/failures within switch statement inside the response closure:

```
Alamofire.request(URLRouter.Products, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
.validate()    
.responseObject { response in
    switch response.result {
        case .success:
            //print("...HTTP code: \ (response.response?.statusCode)")

        case .failure(let error as NSError):
            print("Error: \(error)")

        default:
            print("Unexpected case")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did so but unfortunately now I get an error saying "Ambiguous reference to member 'request(_:method:parameters:encoding:headers:)' "

Comment: I've rewritten the request.